# What's about videofiles on webpages?

Tags: html, video, mp4

I have some trouble getting my .mp4-videofiles working. I have edited my .htaccess with the necesserary addTypes, right html5-video-tags ect, but still some of them WON'T show!
I have now tried converting them from .mp4 to .mp4 wich made some of them work live on web.

But heres the real issue that i really can't figure out why it is so:
All my videoes works very well in both MediaPlayer and VLC, BUT, when i lay them on my website, the videoes won't work. I have tried access them via a direct link and the "corrupted" ones won't work while the working ones works.
What it tells me is that i have the wrong MIME-types (No video source found with the supporting MIME-type) - correct translated? ;)

All videos have the same video-html-settings:

```
<video width="300px" height="168px" preload controls>
       <source src="path-to-video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

What is wrong?! :S I'm have no experience at all in videoes and Google comes up with nothing, than i can use some weird looking "ConvertThisToMP4" or "LetMeFixYourMP4"-programs...

Hope you guys will help me or lead me on the right way :)
Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: What browser are you using? Sounds like your 'mp4' is not really an 'mp4'.

Comment: Mainly FireFox, but the problem is the same in Safari and IE.

Answer (score 0):

mp4 for web and mp4 for playback in VLC are different things. You'll get different mp4 video support depending on your web browser, though most modern browsers will handle mp4 in some way.

mp4 is a 'container' format, and as such can contain video compressed with many different video and audio [codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec). For an mp4 video file to work in a web browser it needs to be encoded with the h264 video codec and AAC audio codec. Some browsers are even more specific and require videos to be encoded with 'baseline' h264 which uses a simple/fast to decompress version of h264 (this is generally for mobile browsers).

You should have a look at your video files using a media inspector to check what the codecs are for the videos. in VLC you can do this from tools->media information then choosing the 'codec' tab.

You can use handbrake ( http://handbrake.fr )  or mpegstreamclip ( http://www.squared5.com ) to recompress the videos to h264/aac/

As an aside, In your HTML you don't need the px values in the width and height tags, inside HTML all size values are assumed to be px, it's only in CSS you need to define the unit.

Comment: Thx for the links. Handbrake looks like a very nice tool! But i really don't get it with the movie-files.

I have tried with a few settings like "Web optimized". But the first file got the ending .mp4 and the second one ended up with .m4v?! I don't really get it...

Comment: the .temp file is created whilst being converted, and the final file will be a .mp4. .m4v is a variation on a .mp4 container which was created by Apple, primarily to allow for DRM.